# Как посчитать потраченную сумму за последний месяц в SQL?

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица transaction_details:

| transaction_id | customer_id | item_id | item_number | transaction_dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7765 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 1254 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 2022-02-03 |
| 3332 | 3 | 56 | 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 7658 | 1 | 43 | 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 7231 | 4 | 56 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 7231 | 2 | 23 | 2 | 2022-01-29 |

Мне необходимо сформировать таблицу следующего вида customer_aggr::

| customer_id | amount_spent_lm | top_item_lm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 700 | glasses |
| 2 | 20000 | notebook |
| 3 | 100 | cup |

При расчете необходимо учитывать актуальную цену на момент совершения транзакции (таблица dict_item_prices). Клиенты, не совершавшие покупок в последний месяц, в итоговую таблицу не попадают. Последний месяц определяется как последние 30 дней на момент построения отчета.

Таблица dict_item_prices:

| item_id | item_name | item_price | valid_from_dt | valid_to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | phone 1 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 12 | notebook | 5000 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 56 | cup | 50 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 43 | glasses | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Comment: а где ваш неработающий вариант?

Comment: *Мне необходимо сформировать таблицу следующего вида customer_aggr* Невозможно. Данные. показанные в результате, отсутствуют в исходных данных.